# ActionScript - Passing & Instantiating Class Reference Containing Required Parameters?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, parameters, reference, instantiation

I'm unsuccessfully attempting to instantiate a reference of a class that is passed as a parameter to another class.

in this example there are 3 classes: **MainClass, Canvas, MyCircle**

from the MainClass i am creating an instance of Canvas, which is passed a class reference of MyCircle as i want to create instances of MyCircle from within Canvas.  however, the MyCircle constructor contains required parameters that are created from within Canvas.

how can i pass and instantiate a class reference with required parameters?

**MyCircle:**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Shape;

    //Class
    public class MyCircle extends Shape
    {
        //Constructor
        public function MyCircle(color:uint, radius:uint)
        {
            graphics.beginFill(color, 1.0);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

**Canvas:**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    //Class
    public class Canvas extends Sprite
    {
        //Constructor
        public function Canvas(circleClassReference:String, amount:uint)
        {
            var CircleReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(circleClassReference) as Class;

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                var randomColor:uint = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
                var randomRadius:uint = Math.random() * 100 + 50;

                var circleInstance:DisplayObject = new CircleReference(randomColor, randomRadius);
                circleInstance.y = i * randomRadius;

                addChild(circleInstance);   
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**MainClass:**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    //Class
    public class MainClass extends Sprite
    {
        //Constructor
        public function MainClass()
        {
            var myCanvas:Canvas = new Canvas("MyCircle", 10);
            addChild(myCanvas)
        }
    }
}
```

---

**[EDIT]**

---

it seems that passing the actual Class instead of the name of the class avoids the need for the dirty fix that is mentioned below.

**MainClass Constructor**

```
public function MainClass()
{   
    var myCanvas:Canvas = new Canvas(MyCircle, 10);
    addChild(myCanvas)
}
```

**Canvas Constructor**

```
public function Canvas(circleClassReference:Class, amount:uint)
{
    var CircleReference:Class = circleClassReference;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        var randomColor:uint = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
        var randomRadius:uint = Math.random() * 100 + 50;

        var circleInstance:DisplayObject = new CircleReference(randomColor, randomRadius);
        circleInstance.y = i * randomRadius;

        addChild(circleInstance);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually import the circle class anywhere?  As far as I know you're doing it right, but I don't see how the code can have imported the MyCircle class at compile time. What error are you getting?

Comment: in this example all 3 classes are within the same package directory so i don't need to import.  i receive `ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable MyCircle is not defined.` which throws an error in the Canvas class at this line:  `var CircleReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(circleClassReference) as Class;`

Comment: If you do not reference `MyCircle` anywhere in your code, the class won't be included by the compiler. Add something like `private static var dummy:MyCircle` in your MainClass class members and try again.

Comment: @bummzack - I prefer to include it as a local variable, it doesn't need to live very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing (or being in the same package) isn't enough to make the compiler include a class definition in the Application Domain.  You will actually have to use the class you want somewhere, or embed the definition in an SWF that you load in.  This should fix your error though:

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    //Class
    public class MainClass extends Sprite
    {
        //Constructor
        public function MainClass()
        {
            //unused variable definition for class embedding purposes
            var tempCircle:MyCircle;
            var myCanvas:Canvas = new Canvas("MyCircle", 10);
            addChild(myCanvas)
        }
    }
}
```

While this will prevent MyCircle from being undefined later on, I've always thought of it as a bit of a dirty fix (despite having it in some fairly major projects).  I'd love to know a better solution, other than embedding the definition in a separate SWF.

Comment: would it be possible to kill two birds with one stone here by passing the actual class instead of the name of the class?  IE:  `public function Canvas(circleClassReference:Class, amount:uint)`?

Comment: If this was an API, I would probably make the user instantiate the class before passing it, and require that their DisplayObject extends an API class to force any functionality you require. It is a limitation that comes up frequently, and I've not seen a satisfactory solution yet.

Comment: ah, it appears i can, which would avoid having to use this fix.  i'll update my code to show this solution, but i'll accept your answer since it was actually correct for what i was attempting to do at first.

Comment: Nice. This error usually bites me when trying to load class references in externally at runtime, which as far as I know still can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you can treat classes as Objects?

Depending on what you're trying to do you could do something like this:

My Circle:

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Shape;

    //Class
    public class MyCircle extends Shape
    {
        //Constructor
        public function MyCircle(color:uint, radius:uint);
        {
            graphics.beginFill(color, 1.0);
            graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, radius);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

Canvas:

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    //Class
    public class Canvas extends Sprite
    {
        //Constructor
        public function Canvas(classToCreate:Class, amount:uint)
        {
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                var randomColor:uint = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
                var randomRadius:uint = Math.random() * 100 + 50;

                var circleInstance:DisplayObject = new classToCreate(randomColor, randomRadius);
                circleInstance.y = i * randomRadius;

                addChild(circleInstance);   
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

MainClass:

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    //Class
    public class MainClass extends Sprite
    {
        //Constructor
        public function MainClass()
        {
            var myCanvas:Canvas = new Canvas(MyCircle, 10);
            addChild(myCanvas)
        }
    }
}
```